# display monkey with power bi

Tags: azure, powerbi

we like to use Display Monkey (www.displaymonkey.org) to show power bi pages on digital signage monitors.

To do that we have to add a new app to our azure portal and then we have to setup a new azure account in Display Monkey, but we always get the message that our windows credentials are not valid.

We think the problem is the start and redirect URL in the azure portal that we have to enter with the app registration.

Our Display Monkey installation is running on a local URL, maybe this could be the problem.

The instructions on the Display Monkey page seem to be outdated and are not really clear about this URLs:
http://www.displaymonkey.org/dm/documentation/other/microsoft-azure-account

It would be nice if someone could help.

thanks in advance
Frank

Comment: ok, meanwhile I got the info that a local URL should not be the problem.
On the DisplayMonkey page where I have to set up the Azure Account I get this error Message: 

AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password, Trace ID: 0de83c86-36e1-4e9c-8c77-3880eb2c1300, Correlation ID: 37de0774-2de6-4583-8ffb-1effae2bb8e4, Timestamp: 2018-03-05 10:06:54Z 

But my credentials are valid if you use them for login directly.